# Nested element in button element are not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having this problem, I created a button, and inside I have a  for Icon, and inside the  element I have span to style the text next to the Icon (the Icon from is humberger from awesome font)

the issue is:
in javascript, I created an onclick function for the button element using the ID btnm, but when I click on the text or the icon in the button does work though when I click around the text and the icon in the button the onclick works fine.
I cannot understand why the icon and text are in the button.
please help

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    var menubtn = document.getElementById('btnm');
    var mobilemenu = document.getElementById('navigation-mobile');

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    menubtn.onclick = function() {
        if (mobilemenu.style.display == 'block') {
            mobilemenu.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            mobilemenu.style.display = 'block';
        }
        
    }
}
```

```css
.mobile-menu-btn {
        float: right;
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
}

        
.humberger {
    background-color: $identity-color;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: $identity-color;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;  
}

.menu-pargraph {
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class ="mobile-menu-btn">
  <button class="humberger" id="btnm">
    <i class="menu-btn fas fa-bars">
      <span class="menu-pargraph">Menu</span>
    </i>
  </button>
</div>

<div id="navigation-mobile">
  <ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>video</li>
    <li>contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post specifying what work and what doesn't? It's quite confusing now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanations in comments below. You had the id (and click listener) on the div, not the button and your 'Menu' text was probably looking funky b/c it was inside the icon element, inheriting the icon font family.

```
<div class ="mobile-menu-btn">
  <button class="humberger" id="btnm"> <!-- put the id here -->
    <i class="menu-btn fas fa-bars"></i>
      <span class="menu-pargraph">Menu</span> <!-- move outside of the fontawesome icon -->
  </button>
</div>
```

Also you can make your life easier with the show/hide using a class

css:

```
#navigation-mobile{
  display:none;
  /* and whatever other styles you have here */
}
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

then in your script:

```
  menubtn.onclick = function() {
    mobilemenu.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

Comment: Thank you I followed your instruction and it works better, though I found out the issue is generated from another event.
I did that and it helped,


window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target !== mobilemenu && event.target !== menubtn ) {
            mobilemenu.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

I also tried using a classList.toggle in it

 the window.onclick work but when it is active and I press on the button the menu appears, but when I click on the text "menu" it doesn't appear (by appear I mean the display change to block)

Comment: it worked after I removed the span and just added menu text to the button itself instead of span.
thank you for the help

Comment: @HamzeChalhoub You're welcome - if you feel this helped solve your issue, pls mark it as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You missed a ")" in your JS code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    var menubtn = document.getElementById('btnm');
    var mobilemenu = document.getElementById('navigation-mobile');

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    console.log("ok")
}
) // Here you have to add parenthesis
```